# Remove highlighted text from a cell in TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

[image: View]

Depending on the status of each pin in the map, each cell in the TableView displays a different color. For changing each color I've not used `UIColor.someColor()` method, in fact I've used:

```
UIColor(red: 28/255, green: 198/255, blue: 25/255, alpha: 0.4) //Light red
```

I would like to remove that highlighted color that is appearing inside each cell. Don't k now if this is a code issue or is something that is inside the TableView/Cell atributes.

I am setting the colors inside the ViewController:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell
    if cell == nil {

        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value2, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }


    cell!.textLabel!.text = myFeed.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("NOMBRE") as? String

    var aux: String = "BLIBRES"
    var aux2: String = "ALIBRES"
    var estado: String = "ESTADO"

    cell!.detailTextLabel!.text = "Anclajes Libres: \(myFeed.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey(aux2)!) | Bicicletas Libres: \(myFeed.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey(aux)!)"

    if myFeed.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey(estado)! as! String == "NO COMUNICA" {

        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 28/255, green: 198/255, blue: 25/255, alpha: 0.4)
    } else if myFeed.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey(estado)! as! String == "COMUNICA" {

        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 218/255, green: 71/355, blue: 71/255, alpha: 0.4)
    } else if myFeed.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey(estado)! as! String == "ALARMAS" {

        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 248/255, green: 155/255, blue: 18/255, alpha: 0.4)
    }

    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Which color you mean? The background color behind the text only(dark green), or the light-green color?

Comment: Show how and where you're setting the colour, and explain the code trigger to remove it.

Comment: The dark color, the light green background color is the correct one. I've added the code that adds the background color to the post. It might me a setting of the TableView or  cell what needs a change not the code I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I did not know that apart from setting a background color to the cell itself, you can set a background color to the text (and also detailText) of the cell. Inside the `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { }` method add the following:

```
cell?.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
cell?.detailTextLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

And then the text is displayed correctly without the borders that looked like a highlighted text when setting a custom background color to a cell.

[image: Solved unwanted highlighted text problem!]